# Unable to import python library that I created

Tags: python, pypi

For the past few hours, I've been trying to correctly upload a library to PyPI, but without success. I already managed to upload it to PyPI and even download it with *pip*, but always when I try to import it I get the following error:

```
    import pseudopython-org
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I already tried 2 different Youtube tutorials, running it on Ubuntu, on Google Collaboratory, but nothing seems to work. So, I believe it must be something either with my folder structure or the setup.py file.

My folder structure currently looks like this:

```
d-----        23/01/2022     22:36                dist
d-----        23/01/2022     22:41                pseudopython-org
d-----        23/01/2022     22:36                pseudopython_org.egg-info
-a----        23/01/2022     20:57             81 CHANGELOG.txt
-a----        23/01/2022     20:58           1061 LICENSE.txt
-a----        23/01/2022     20:58             25 MANIFEST.in
-a----        23/01/2022     21:54            369 README.md
-a----        23/01/2022     22:35            910 setup.py
```

Inside the `pseudopython-org` folder I have 2 files:

****init**.py**

`from py_to_pseudocode import python_to_pseudocode`

**py_to_pseudocode.py**

```
def python_to_pseudocode(python_code):
    some logic
    return something
```

And my `setup.py` looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


VERSION = '0.0.3'
DESCRIPTION = 'Converting Python code snippets to Pseudocode effectively.'
LONG_DESCRIPTION = 'Converting Python code snippets to Pseudocode effectively.'

# Setting up
setup(
    name="pseudopython-org",
    version=VERSION,
    author="anonymouscoolguy",
    author_email="<anonymouscoolguy05@gmail.com>",
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    long_description=LONG_DESCRIPTION,
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[],
    keywords=['pseudocode', 'python'],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 1 - Planning",
        "Intended Audience :: Education",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: Unix",
        "Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
    ]
)
```

For a more detailed look at the files you can always download the [repository](https://pypi.org/project/pseudopython-org/#files) in PyPI.

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, and any input is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: python identifiers cannot contain `-` -- that's subtraction, you want an underscore `_`

Comment: Hey Anthony, I already tried with the underscore, but it automatically creates with an '-' and does not work either. Then I created a new library called 'python2pseudocode', just to test and does not work either. Gives the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python2pseudocode'

https://pypi.org/project/python2pseudocode/

Comment: Change your folder structure. Rename the directory `pseudopython-org` to `pseudopython_org`.

Comment: And change `from py_to_pseudocode import python_to_pseudocode` to `from .py_to_pseudocode import python_to_pseudocode` (i.e. with a dot to denote an import from a module in the current package).

Comment: You can use `pseudopython_org = __import__('pseudopython-org')` to import the module without changing the name of the directory.

Comment: But I think that it's best to actually remove `-org` completely and let the folder name be `pseudopython` and have `name="pseudopython"` in setup.py.

Comment: You can also import using function `__import__("pseudopython-org")`, but it would be much much better to follow convention and do not name packages with ''-'' in name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some long hours and help from the community, I finally managed to solve the problem.

Here is what I did:

- Renamed my package to `python2pseudocode` so it won't have any '-', as suggested by Anthony in the comments.
- Renamed the folder which contains the `__init__.py` file to the same as the package, as suggested by *md2perpe*
- And finally, put all my code in the `__init__.py` file, so I won't have any mysterious imports.

Thanks for all the help, greatly appreciated.